# Sorting Arrays or collections

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code as a sub in Excel 2010:

```
i = 2

For j = 1 To num_scenarios

Dim probdiff As Double
Dim OCS_Spend As Double
n = 0

For k = 1 To num_yrs


' These are the calculations and potentially not relevant to my question but here for context    
For Each cell In rng

x = Rnd()
'Debug.Print Format(x, "0.00000%")
If cell.Value >= x Then

'Populate the result sheet

Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 1) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 1)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 2) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 2)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 3) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 3)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 4) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 4)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 5) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 5)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 6) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 6)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 10) = "Event Occurs"
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 11) = mywksht.Cells(cell.Row, 11)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 9) = x
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 7) = k
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 8) = j
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 14) = (cell.Value - x) ^ (2)
event_max = Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 11)
probdiff = probdiff + (cell.Value - x) ^ (2)

If Round(cell / x, 0) >= event_max Then
    Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 12) = event_max
    Else
        Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 12) = Round(cell / x, 0)
End If
Duration = Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 4)
Num_Event = Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 12)
Spend = Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 5)
Sheets("Event Occurs").Cells(i, 13) = Num_Event * Spend / Duration
OCS_Spend = OCS_Spend + Num_Event * Spend / Duration

n = n + 1
i = i + 1

End If

Next cell

' End calculations

Next k

Debug.Print j, probdiff / n


probdiff = 0
OCS_Spend = 0
Next j
```

The output to the immediate window looks like this:

```
 J:               MSE:
 1             0.194236476623154 
 2             0.157939130921924 
 3             0.19825548826238 
 4             0.384990330451172 
 5             0.267128221022187
```

The first column is j (the outer for loop) and represents a scenario.  The second column is the mean square error of the data generated by each iteration of the outer j loop.  So 1 is the first time the loop runs,2 is the second etc..  The smaller the number in column MSE, the more likely the scenario is to occur.

I want people to be able to limit the number of scenarios (j's) they see to only the most likely in the event they want to run 100 scenarios.  So I need a way of sorting the table above to something like this

```
j:                MSE        
2             0.157939130921924 
1             0.194236476623154 
3             0.19825548826238 
5             0.267128221022187
4             0.384990330451172
```

And if someone wanted to see only the top three results, it would be this:

```
j:                MSE        
2             0.157939130921924 
1             0.194236476623154 
3             0.19825548826238
```

So basically the three most likely out of 5 possible scenarios.  I have tried collections and arrays but not dicitonaries (I am still learning how to use these and not sure if they exists in Excel VBA).

Comment: Have either of the answers helped you solve your problem yet?  If so, do consider [marking one of them as "Accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `System.Collections.ArrayList` since this object directly supports a `Sort` method.  The Object is "borrowed" from VB.NET.

**EDIT#1**

Here is a sample:

```
Sub SortDemo()
    s = Array("Larry", "Moe", "Curley", "Manny", "Zack", "Jack")
    L = LBound(s)
    U = UBound(s)
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For k = L To U
            .Add s(k)
        Next k
        .Sort
        s = .toarray
    End With

    msg = ""
    For k = L To U
        msg = msg & s(k) & vbCrLf
    Next k
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

and here are the references in place:

[image: demo]

For more information see:

[Ozgrid Material](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=167349)

Comment: This question is about Excel VBA, not VB.NET.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You can use this Object in VBA, I will update my answer later!

Comment: will this keep the scenario identifier.  I can sort the MSE data alone with a collection.  but I can't also get it to write the key to the sheet. Although I may just be unaware of how to do this.  But the user needs to be able to read both the MSE and the accompanying scenario (ie 'j').

Comment: I also always get a type mismatch error when I try to put 'j' as the collection key.

Comment: @user2907249 For the type mismatch use **CStr(j)** rather than **j** _____my post is only a sample.  For more info, see the reference I will add to the bottom of my post.

Comment: this works well enough.  What is the ".toarray" function doing.  I hav never seen it and when I comment it out the macro still works.

Comment: **.ToArray** should place *ArrayList* back into the *array*

Comment: actually this works perfectly.  I just changes "Add s(k)" to ' .Add s(k) & " " & k ' and I can print the order in which it was added to the array.

Comment: The *ArrayList* is quite useful _________it is worth reviewing the OZGRID material.

Answer (score 2):

Chip Pearson provides a number of very useful functions which can sort arrays, collections, and dictionaries, which are available here:

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/SortingArrays.aspx

There is too much code there to reproduce here. What I typically do when the need arises is to create a separate module in my VBProject which contains these array helper functions.  I have used these extensively in PowerPoint and they worked in that environment with minimal modifications. For Excel, they *should* work out-of-the-box.

Once you have put the data in an array (I don't see any arrays in your code, so let's assume you have something like `Dim MyArray As Variant`), and sorted it using those functions, you can do something like this to cut the array down to include only the first `x` results:

```
'where "x" is a long/integer represents some user-input or _
  limit to the number of results:
ReDim Preserve MyArray(x - 1)
```

I would use arrays rather than collections or dictionaries.

**Why not Collections?** Collections are useful and would arguably do the job, here. However, whereas we can "resize" the array in a single `ReDim Preserve` statement, you cannot do that with a Collection object; you would instead have to use iteration. While this is not overly complicated, it does seem a bit clunkier.  (You could of course do some tests on performance, but unless you are dealing with very large sets of data, I would not expect a noticeable gain either way).

```
Sub testCollection()
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
coll.Add i
Next

Dim x As Integer 'The maximum number of results you want to return:
x = 4
Do Until coll.Count = x
    coll.Remove (coll.Count)
Loop

End Sub
```

**Why not dictionaries?**  While a dictionary's `.Keys` returns a one-dimensional array of values, in order to avoid iteration (like in the collection object) you would still need to transfer these to an array:

```
MyArray = dict.Keys()
ReDim Preserve MyArray(x-1)
```

Further, the dictionary object holds unique *key* values, so these are not good to use if you anticipate that there may be duplicate values that you need to store.

Comment: Yeah I don't have any arrays yet.  I am not sure though which is best to use.  Array, collection, dictionary or something else.

Comment: I would use arrays in this circumstance. Collections and Dictionaries are objects that have a few useful methods but I don't think it would be necessary, and would actually be slightly more complicated to "resize" them down to a specific number of results. I will update my answer to offer a bit of explanation.